# MongoDB Update: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I am trying to update a certain coin information in my database with this function:

```
const updateCoin = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 const { coinId, seconds, bidAmount } = req.body;
```

`const coin = await Coin.findById({itemId: coinId})`;

```
  if (coin) {
    (coin.coinimage = coinImage),
      (coin.coinTitle = coinTitle),
      (coin.bids = bids),
      (coin.timeLeft = timeLeft),
      (coin.currentBid = currentBid),
      (coin.seconds = seconds),
      (coin.bidAmount = bidAmount);

    const updatedCoin = await coin.save();
    res.json(updatedCoin);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('Coin Not Found');
  }
```

However in my Postman i am getting an error of : CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

I am passing the ID as a string in postman... and the id is correct in the database... why is it giving me an error???

Comment: Did you remodel your id field from ```_id``` to ```itemId``` ?

Comment: please provide a sample document from your database.